# How to set left alignement JLabel in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have a JPanel that I insert into my JFrame.
Now, I want to display a JLabel on the left at my JPanel. So I have this code:

```
JPanel panelHeader = new JPanel();
panelHeader.setBackground(new Color(52,151,236));
panelHeader.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,25));

GridBagConstraints GBC = new GridBagConstraints();
Container CR = new Container();
GridBagLayout GBL = new GridBagLayout();
CR.setLayout(GBL);     
panelHeader.add(CR);

LabelFormat label = new LabelFormat("EasyManagement",new Font("Arial Narrow", Font.PLAIN, 16),Color.white);
GBC = new GridBagConstraints();
CR.add(label);
GBC.gridx=0;
GBC.gridy=0;
GBC.insets.left = 1;
GBC.insets.top=0;
GBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
GBC.anchor= GridBagConstraints.EAST;
GBL.setConstraints(label,GBC);
```

With this code, I'm not able to display the JLabel at the left on JPanel but I see it on the center.

How can I fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-You might wish to set the JLabel's horizontalAlignment property. One way is via its constructor. Try:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(lText, SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

This can also be done via the expected setter method:

```
label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

-You can also try using LEFT alignment for your JLabel JPanel container

```
myJPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

-Final way :

You could wrap the label in `JPanel` with `FlowLayout.LEADING`

```
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING,0, 0));
wrapper.add(Jlabel);
panel.add(wrapper);
```

[image]

---

Also remember to follow Java naming convention. variables begin with lower case letters using camel casing: `Jlabel` → `jLabel`